# Django: Selecting different divs while indexing a list inside one, HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have two divs that are toggled between dislpay:none and display:inline through the same javascript function. This is working properly, however, I want to also index the outliers_data list at some integer value based on what is passed into the javascript function. I am not sure how to best accomplish this task. Here is my html:

```
<div id="outlier_list" style="display: inline">
    <label style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 24px;">Outliers</label><br>
    {% for val, name in outliers %}
        <label onclick="swapOutlierContent({{ forloop.counter }})" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;">{{ val }} </label>
        <label style="font-style: italic;">{{ name }}</label><br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<div id="outlier_data" style="display: none;">
    <label style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 24px;">Outlier In-Depth</label><br>
    {% for val, name in outliers_data %}
        <label onclick="swapOutlierContent({{ forloop.counter }})" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;">{{ val }} </label>
        <label style="font-style: italic;">{{ name }}</label><br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<script>
    function swapOutlierContent(outlier_id) {
        outlier_list = document.getElementById('outlier_list');
        outlier_data = document.getElementById('outlier_data');
        if (outlier_list.style.display == 'inline'){
            outlier_list.style.display = 'none'
        }
        else {
            outlier_list.style.display = 'inline'
        }
        if (outlier_data.style.display == 'inline'){
            outlier_data.style.display = 'none'
        }
        else {
            outlier_data.style.display = 'inline'
        }
    }
</script>
```

I would like the `{% for val, name in outliers_data %}` to become something like `{% for val, name in outliers_data.index %}` but my current structure seems wrong for this.

Thanks

Comment: This might not be the best idea but have you considered parsing the data in a javascript object and use it ? Or maybe just create another div with outliers_data.index and you can just keep changing display as you want.

Comment: @Batman How would I parse the object in javascript? Do you mean passing the outliers_data object and then handling it in the script? I am pretty unfamiliar with JS.

Comment: Since you know hot to use Django variables in template you can simply assign the value to the variable.
lets say: var batman = '{{ bruce }}'

Comment: I would personally suggest to include jQuery in your project as well, since you are new to javascript, it'll make things easier for you ! (It worked greatly for me)

Comment: Thank you! I will try these things out. I was unsure for so long if it was acceptable to use JS or jQuery in Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I used another Django template loop to create a dynamic amount of outlier divs based on the list length of outliers_list. I can then reference the specific div name using the `forloop.counter` value appended onto the end with `document.getElementById`. I then added a back button to be able to return to the list view and hide the detailed page.

```
        <div id="outlier_list" style="display: inline">
            <label style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 24px;">Outliers</label><br>
            {% for val, name in outliers %}
                <label onclick="swapToOutlierContent({{ forloop.counter }})" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;">{{ val }} </label>
                <label style="font-style: italic;">{{ name }}</label><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% for outlier in outliers_data %}
            <div id="outlier_data_{{ forloop.counter }}" style="display: none;">
                <label style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 24px;">Outlier In-Depth</label><br>
                {% for val, name in outlier %}
                    <!-- Get the parent counter -->
                    <label onclick="swapOutlierContent({{ forloop.parentloop.counter }})" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;">{{ val }} </label>
                    <label style="font-style: italic;">{{ name }}</label><br>
                {% endfor %}
                <input type="button" onclick="swapToOutlierList({{ forloop.counter }})">
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <script>
            function swapToOutlierContent(outlier_id) {
                outlier_list_div = document.getElementById('outlier_list');
                outlier_data_div = document.getElementById('outlier_data_' + outlier_id);

                outlier_list_div.style.display = 'none';
                outlier_data_div.style.display = 'inline';
            }
            function swapToOutlierList(outlier_id) {
                outlier_list_div = document.getElementById('outlier_list');
                outlier_data_div = document.getElementById('outlier_data_' + outlier_id);

                outlier_list_div.style.display = 'inline';
                outlier_data_div.style.display = 'none';
            }
        </script>
```

This may not be the best or most efficient way but it accomplishes what I was trying to do.

Comment: Using parentloop was a neat trick! Glad you fixed it yourself! May the Force be with you!

Answer (score 0):

We will add a common class among all the elements.

```
<div id="outlier_list" class="outliers" style="display: inline">
    <label style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 24px;">Outliers</label><br>
    {% for val, name in outliers %}
        <label onclick="swapOutlierContent({{ forloop.counter }})" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;">{{ val }} </label>
        <label style="font-style: italic;">{{ name }}</label><br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<div id="outlier_data" class="outliers" style="display: none;">
    <label style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 24px;">Outlier In-Depth</label><br>
    {% for val, name in outliers_data %}
        <label onclick="swapOutlierContent({{ forloop.counter }})" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;">{{ val }} </label>
        <label style="font-style: italic;">{{ name }}</label><br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<div id="outlier_data_index" class="outliers" style="display: none;">
    <label style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 24px;">Outlier In-Depth</label><br>
    {% for val, name in outliers_data.index %}
        <label onclick="swapOutlierContent({{ forloop.counter }})" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;">{{ val }} </label>
        <label style="font-style: italic;">{{ name }}</label><br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Whenever the function is called, we first hide all elements with the common class, later we show the one which is appropriate.

(I've used jQuery since i find it easier, if you want this can be done in javascript too but with a little more code)

```
<script>
    function swapOutlierContent(outlier_id) {
        $(".outliers").css('display','none');
        if (outlier_id === 1){
            $("#outlier_list).css('display','inline')
        }
        else if(outlier_id === 2){
            $("#outlier_data).css('display','inline')
        }
        else {
            $("#outlier_data_index).css('display','inline')
        }
    }
</script>
```

I didn't really understand why you send in the for loop counter as a parameter to the function so I modified it to take the number of the div to be shown, you can either replace that or send in 2 parameters.

Comment: I did not specify very well all of my thoughts for what I was trying to accomplish. Your answer did quite capture what I was trying to do but it made me ask the right questions. I will add my solution.